# Google Wave CLI client and googlewave.com

Tags: command-line-interface, google-wave

I'm trying to use the [CLI client](http://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/wiki/ConsoleClient) for Google Wave that Google have created with my @googlewave.com account.  I can't seem to get it to connect -- does anyone know if this is actually possible, or if it will only connect to locally hosted wave servers?

Answer (score 2):

Have you configured the client with the included script?

...and are you aware the Google Wave [has been decommissioned since August](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/update-on-google-wave.html)?